# how to run single 7W bulb using pc UPS?

Tags: led, ups

Why is it not possible to continuously run a 7W LED bulb alone using a computer UPS? When I tried, the UPS went off after every minute.

Comment: What UPS? is the battery holding a charge? Can you run a higher load for more time? If so then you can't run a small load on that UPS.

Comment: This is not a design question. You should refer to the manual, and possibly take your UPS to the repair center if it doesn't work as described.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably not draining enough power from the UPS. If it thinks there is no load it will shut-down to save the battery.

As such, you need to read the UPS manual to see if there is a mode that disables that feature, or find out the minimum power you need to draw to keep it alive and add that much load.

Comment: One way that you can acheive this load is to add a dummy load like this:
https://cdn.instructables.com/ORIG/FY8/THBO/G33P0IGP/FY8THBOG33P0IGP.png
When I made an atx bench supply I put the dummy load on the 12V rail.

Comment: @Hair_of_the_Dog yup, or add more LEDs.. Nice handle btw LOL.. I love it.

Comment: If only @Hair_of_the_Dog could answer the right question.....

Comment: I skipped over the USP part. :( The idea is still correct though. The USP assumes if you aren't drawing enough power that it can shut down.

Comment: @Hair_of_the_Dog I changed that back to save the battery. It's not just saving power it's keeping the charge on the battery. Not quite the same thing.

Comment: @Trevor I tried to take back the edit, but didn't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Note that driving an AC LED bulb from a computer UPS is dreadfully inefficient. The UPS wastes a lot of power converting 12V dc to AC, even with no power being drawn. That's why it shuts down if the load is too small - to save your battery.

We have bad power outages in my area, so I took a deep cycle marine lead/acid battery and attached some 12V LED landscape lights to it.

If memory serves, I calculated that 2 very bright LED bulbs would run for about 36 hours continuously on the battery I used.